# The Alpha or Gamma role in Apache Superset can't edit Dashboard

Tags: dashboard, roles, apache-superset

[image]

I can't find the right authority name on the Role Page to enable Gamma to edit the dashboard

I want to know how to get the authority to edit the dashboard for the Gamma role, and is there any official document to explain the exact meaning of each authority name in the Role page

[image]